# TinyMCE <textarea> two way bound with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, binding, tinymce

Is it possible to apply two way binding to a `<textarea></textarea>` that has had TinyMCE applied to it for Rich Text Formatting.

I can't get it to work! I can get TinyMCE to load the content of my model, but when I update the text in TinyMCE, my model does not auto update!

Is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by creating your own directive.

What you need to do is to let your directive sync your model when something in the TinyMCE editor changes. I have not used TinyMCE, but Wysihtml5. I think you can remake this to use TinyMCE instead.

```
angular.module('directives').directive('wysihtml5', ['$timeout',
function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: "<textarea></textarea>", // A template you create as a HTML file (use templateURL) or something else...
        link: function ($scope, $element, attrs, ngModel) {

            // Find the textarea defined in your Template
            var textarea = $element.find("textarea");

            // When your model changes from the outside, use ngModel.$render to update the value in the textarea
            ngModel.$render = function () {
                textarea.val(ngModel.$viewValue);
            };

            // Create the editor itself, use TinyMCE in your case
            var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor(textarea[0],
                {
                    stylesheets: ["/style.css"],
                    parserRules: wysihtml5ParserRules,
                    toolbar: true,
                    autoLink: true,
                    useLineBreaks: false,
                });

            // Ensure editor is rendered before binding to the change event
            $timeout(function () {

                // On every change in the editor, get the value from the editor (textarea in case of Wysihtml5)
                // and set your model
                editor.on('change', function () {
                    var newValue = textarea.val();

                    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
                        });
                    }
                });

            }, 500);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then you can use the directive in your html page like this:

```
<wysihtml5 ng-model="model.text" />
```

Here's a link if you need more info on creating your own directive: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0):

Also compare the render function from the directive above to this render function from angular-ui-tinymce ( https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce )

```
ngModel.$render = function() {
  if (!tinyInstance) {
    tinyInstance = tinymce.get(attrs.id);
  }
  if (tinyInstance) {
    tinyInstance.setContent(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
  }
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/04AFkp?p=preview

However depending on the timing of the loading of your DOM you may need to set the priority on your directive upwards. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using a custom angular directive.
You'll need to use jQuery with angularJS, TinyMCE 4 and their jQuery plugin.

```
myApp.directive('tinymce', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'C',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
         element.tinymce({
            setup: function (e) {
               e.on("change", function() {
                  modelCtrl.$setViewValue(element.val());
                  scope.$apply();
               }
            }
         });
      }
   }
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<textarea class="tinymce" ng-model="data"></textarea>
```

That's it, have fun.