# Binding value into TinyMCE <textarea> using AngularJS model

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, tinymce-3

I am developing an ASP.net MVC application with AngularJS and TinyMCE.

I need to display a WYSIWYG textarea to the user to get input.

I am not able to bind initial value into the textarea. Need help. The following is what I have done.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "advanced",
        theme_advanced_path: false,
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "fontselect,|,bold,italic,underline,|,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,link,unlink,|,bullist,numlist,|,code",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,
    });
</script>
```

View:

```
<textarea data-ng-model="selectedProduct.ProductText">
  {{selectedProduct.ProductText}}
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to use this library: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce
Things get much easier then. A sample:

```
<textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="tinymceModel"></textarea>

myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.tinymceOptions = {
            //enter any options here
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: is it a freeware? and I am using TinyMCE version 3.5.8

Comment: Good question. Yes it is. The license can be found here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: It is compatible with version 4+ of TinyMCE, you would have to upgrade then. If you can't or don't want to, I would look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005699/tinymce-textarea-two-way-bound-with-angularjs

Comment: I need help in downloading the library you are mentioning. In the link you provided what file(s) should I download?

Comment: This is the only file you need to download: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/blob/master/src/tinymce.js Add it to your application as dependency: `var myAppModule = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.tinymce'])`

Comment: I upgraded TinyMCE version to 4.0.0 and the expected was achieved thanks to you. I face a new problem like when I try to re-size the textarea the width gets reduced until I release the key press. How can I disable the re-size option in 4.0.0 and also need to remove the Menu strip from the element how can I achieve this too?